# How to normalise(?) an [x,y] time series data set

Tags: time-series, regression, graphs

**Problem:**

I'm currently parsing a time series dataset, of `[x,y]` coordinates. The data isn't complete - it contains gaps and jitter, and I would like to fill these gaps / normalise the jitter using statistical analysis.

**Background:**

I'm currently reading up on non-linear regression (specifically polynomial regression -> PR) - which seems to be the best fit (pun intended) for my problem.

I realise that PR deals with arcs "turning in one direction" so, I'm going to try to refactor my code to work with smaller sample sizes - and work my way along the time series.

**Questions:**

1. Am I on the right track?
2. Is there a name for what I'm trying to do? i.e. using polynomial regression across an ongoing graph (curve fitting? trendline? continuous regression?)
3. Is there another technique I can/should use, that provides a better "fit" for my data?

Comment: For regression problems, usually standardisation is more useful than normalisation. I don’t have experience with what you are doing. I always consider RNN for first attempts for these types of problems.